# Can some explain what this property does?

Tags: rest, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

Can some explain what this property does?

```
ClientProperites.FEATURE_AUTO_DISCOVERY_DISABLE

"jersey.config.disableAutoDiscovery.client"
```

I am trying to figure out the actual meaning of it.

http://javadox.com/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-client/2.6/org/glassfish/jersey/client/ClientProperties.html#FEATURE_AUTO_DISCOVERY_DISABLE

Answer (score 0):

There is an interface `AutoDiscoverable`, that when implemented, allows features to be discovered, registered, and configured automatically. Be default, this auto-discoverable feature is turned on. If you turn it off, then you will lose a lot of features that would have been automatically registered. You will need to register them yourself.

One example would be the Jackson JSON support. Just by adding the `jersey-media-json-jackson` dependency, it comes with a `JacksonAutoDiscoverable` that registers the `JacksonFeature` (which provides all the JSON support), and we would not have to register it explicitly.

Unless you have a real necessity to disable this feature, you should leave it. One reason you *would* want to disable it would be because you do not want to have a certain feature enabled that is enabled by autodiscovery.

The property is suffixed with `client` because you can do the same for the server; disable all the auto-discovered features. That property is suffixed with `server`.

There's a small section in [the docs](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/deployment.html#deployment.autodiscoverable) about Auto-Discoverable Features.